# how to bind a simple json object to a dropdown in knockout?

Tags: knockout.js

I have a simple json object:

```
“{"MediaType":1,"Country":2,"Region":3,"SubRegion":4}"
```

I want to bind it to a drop down so that the resulting html would look like the following. I don't know how to do this as the JSON represents different name and value or better put it is a representation of key value pairs.

```
<option value="1">Media Type</option>
<option value="2">Country</option>
<option value="3">Region</option>
<option value="4">Sub Region</option>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert the JSON key/value pairs into a standard array of JS objects with standardized properties, such as name and value.

```
//this is property that gets passed to the `options` binding
this.items = ko.observableArray();  

//convert json key/value pair into a standardized object array
for (key in jsonResult) {
    var item = {
        name: key,         // Push the key on the array
        value: jsonResult[key] // Push the key's value on the array
    };
    this.items.push(item);
}
```

[**See the Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2bRMw/1/)

Comment: See the updated fiddle, which is a more complete demonstration